# jQuery Slider value gives other result than option value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I have a page with two sliders on the page, nothing special there.
However: I've found a strange issue while working with the values form the slider and with external buttons to control the slider.

This is my slider.

```
var slider = $("#amount_slider").slider({
        value: amount,
        min: min_amount,
        max: max_amount,
        step: step,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#CREDIT").val(ui.value);
            handle_amount.qtip('option', 'content.text', '&euro; ' + FormatNumber(ui.value));
        },
        change: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#CREDIT").trigger('blur');
            Calculate();
        }
    });

console.log($("#amount_slider").slider("value"));
console.log($("#amount_slider").slider("option", "value"));
```

And when I perform these outputs I get two different results!
The result should be 25000, but I get 24500 and 25000.
In ui.value there's also 24500...

I hope somebody can help me :-)

If you want to fiddle around with the bug: http://jsfiddle.net/xzhgd/

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a colleague of mine we've been able to find the issue and a solution.
Given my minimum value of 2500 and steps of 2000 you are unable to reach my given value of 25000, so the slider changes this to 24500 which is in fact reachable.

I think this is a 'design issue' in the UI because I'd rather have my value correct and adjust my minimum and maximum to be more strict. After all you want a correct value and stricter borders still mean a correct value. So here's how I've solved this so it will work 'my way'.

```
var factor = Math.Floor((amount - min_amount) / step);
var real_min = amount - (factor * step);
```

And then I assign real_min as minimum for the slider.